# This sentence pattern is subject-verb, or subject-linking verb-subject structure?

Tags: sentence-structure

> He is running.

This sentence pattern is subject-verb, or subject-linking verb-subject structure?

Comment: Are you asking if "running" is a subject complement, like in, "My sister is a teacher", where "a teacher" is the complement of "my sister"?

Comment: There is no linking verb, that's for sure. He runs everyday. He is running now.

Comment: @Lambie It would be a linking verb if you construed the present participle "running" as a predicate adjective. I realize that that interpretation isn't popular with modern grammars, but I think that that is what OP is wondering. (I think OP meant "subject-linking verb-subject complement", as gotube asked.)

Answer (score 0):

> *He is running.*

The choice of analysis depends on how detailed you want it to be.

In very simple terms, it consists of two constituents: the subject "he" and the predicate verb phrase "is running".

A more detailed (and advanced) analysis shows it to be subject-verb-subordinate clause, where the verb "running" forms a clause serving as complement of the main verb "is".

Comment: "Running" isn't a subordinate clause - it's part of a multi-word verb construction, like the "run" in "he has run".

Comment: @StuartF Nonsense! No one nowadays sensibly talks of 'verb groups'. In "He is running", the gerund-participle verb "running" is a non-finite clause functioning as complement of the catenative verb "is". The same applies to your example: "run" is a past-participial clause functioning as complement of the catenative verb "has".